# Running lualatex after latex while retaining auxiliary files in the presence of colon in labels and nonmain french language

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, auxiliary-files, babel-french, dvi-mode

Let's assume that we have a huge LaTeX document, out of which we produce a PostScript version via `latex`+`dvips` and a PDF version via `lualatex`. Compiling everything from scratch (without any auxiliary files from previous runs) takes long (on my current machine with its current background load, it takes over 1.5 h). Thus, whenever we wish to produce both versions, we would like to save some work and keep as much useful stuff in the auxiliary files as possible (we spend only 68% to 78% of time when reusing the old auxiliary files). However, we get an error on the standard output when we run `lualatex` *after* `latex`  (we assume exactly this order in this particular question) as follows.

To demonstrate the error on a small example, we prepare a file `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{sect:title}% even “sect:” would do
\end{document}
```

Running `rm -f mwe.aux && latex mwe && lualatex mwe` results in

```
(./mwe.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> r@sect:
       title
l.10 \newlabel{sect:title}{{1}{1}}
                                
?
```

on the standard tty output.  Is there a bug / issue / unintended behavior hiding anywhere (e.g., in `babel`)?  How to process `mwe.aux` (while retaining as much useful data as possible there) after the run of `latex` and before the run of `lualatex` such that the error goes away?  We wish to noninteractively edit the auxiliary file, say, via `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `:` in labels at the same time as activating them for French punctuation is playing with fire, but you can write a command to the aux to make it safe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\ifdefined\directlua\else
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\detokenize{%
\ifx:\@undefined\edef:{\string:}\fi
}}}
\makeatother
\fi
\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{sect:title}% even “sect:” would do
\end{document}
```

after the latex run the aux will be

```
\relax 
\providecommand\babel@aux[2]{}
\@nameuse{bbl@beforestart}
\catcode `:\active 
\catcode `;\active 
\catcode `!\active 
\catcode `?\active 
\ifx :\@undefined \edef :{\string :}\fi 
\babel@aux{USenglish}{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Title}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sect:title}{{1}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

and then after lualatex

```
\relax 
\providecommand\babel@aux[2]{}
\@nameuse{bbl@beforestart}
\babel@aux{USenglish}{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Title}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sect:title}{{1}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Is the postscript generated by lualatex; pdftops  not usable?

Comment: Thanks! We use French very scarcely: `\foreignlanguage{french}{Gilles Kahn}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{Dijon}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{rendezvous}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{Bourbaki}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{E II.13, \S 3.4, Définition 9}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{Colloque sur la programmation}`, `\foreignlanguage{french}{Bernard Robinet}`, and `langid={french}` in a few entries of our .bib file. We generate Postscript in the old style via latex + dvips.

Comment: I'm just surprised you don't want the postscript to use the same fonts and layout as the pdf

Comment: Partly, a different generation style is intentional: we wish to catch possible errors that reveal themselves only when the output is slightly different (due to different fonts and layout). Independent thereof, doesn't latex+dvips *in general* produce a cleaner Postscript output in comparison to lualatex+pdf2ps, especially in the presence of `picture` and `tikzpicture` environments?

Comment: I've just now discovered `\gdef \@abspage@last{1}`.  Is `\@abspage@last` a reliable substitute of the label `LastPage` from the package lastpage? We've been using `LastPage` so far in our non-minimal example to determine the horizontal space needed to typeset the largest page number.

Comment: yes it is built in to latex these days

Comment: I've found out just now that `pdftops` is not a typo but a different tool than `pdf2ps` (which takes forever to terminate …).

Comment: On my machine, `/usr/bin/pdftops` is a small binary executable, and `/usr/bin/pdf2ps` is a small shell script indeed calling `gs` .

Comment: oh sorry yes pdftops is from poppler

Comment: lualatex+pdftops yields, for our input, a PostScript file *twice* as large as latex+dvips. (More precisely, the factor varies between 2.02 to 2.54 depending on the input. The comparison is not fully fair because we sometimes employ `\ifTUTeX…\else…\fi` and `\ifpdf…\fi`, e.g., when we construct new symbols or when choosing the options to pass to hyperref.)

Comment: @AlMa0 For a few words and short phrases not requiring the French typographical rules for spacing, best don’t declare it when loading `babel` and just use it with `\foreignlanguage`. See the section “Mostly monolingual documents” in the `babel` docs.

Comment: Wow. `pdf2ps` took 21 min to terminate for our input and returned a file 29 times larger than that from latex+dvips. `pdftops` took only 34 s on the same input and returned a file only twice as large as that from latex+dvips. So, thanks for pointing me to `pdftops`!

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks! This is new: from v3.39. (And this is new to me, too.) Would an entry of a .bib file with `langid={french}` for biblatex+biber be considered a small piece in your sense?

Comment: @JavierBezos Examples: “Stefan Banach. « Sur les opérations dans les ensembles abstraits et leur application aux équations intégrales ». In : Fundamenta Mathematicae 3 (1922), pages 133-181. DOI : 10.4064/fm-3-1-133-181.”, “Nicolas Bourbaki. Théorie des ensembles. Springer Verlag, 2006. ISBN : 978-3-540-34034-8.” from http://pastebin.com/Ffi9T51q .